# docker run in gitlab-ci gives garbled display output

Tags: docker, powershell, gitlab-ci

I am trying to understand what is causing the garbled output in one of my docker/windows run (from gitlab-ci):

[image]

If I execute the docker run locally it display fine.

Dockerfile is simply:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
[...]
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Should I change my `ENTRYPOINT` to something else ?

Comment: Try adding the `-NoProfile` switch, does that help resolve the issue?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [how the powershell runner does it](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/ab435ea32a00e636122b7844b7a78bca721d8536/shells/powershell.go#L107-166) and configure your image to use a similar approach in your entrypoint. I also noticed some non-printable characters showing up in your output. To me, that sounds like an encoding thing. The comments in the linked code talk about this at some length... you'll also notice the use of `[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding` or `-OutputFormat text`

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve my issue as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

This is fundamentally a PEBKAC issue, as I was using the `-t` flag thinking it would refer to the tag name. Turns out that `-t` refers to pseudo-tty and docker run would try to setup some kind of complex output (window title?), which created this garbled output.